# Shell Script For Process Monitoring

Tags: linux, shell

This

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `ps -ef | grep "91.34.124.35" | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 0 ]; then sh home/asfd.sh; fi
```

or this?

```
ps -ef | grep "91\.34\.124\.35" | grep -v grep > /dev/null
if [  "$?" -ne "0" ]
then
sh home/asfd.sh
else
echo "Process is running fine"
fi
```

Hello, how can I write a shell script that looks in running processes and if there isn't a process name **CONTAINING** 91.34.124.35 then execute a file in a certain place and I want to make this run every 30 seconds in a continuous loop, I think there was a sleep command.

Answer (score 4):

you can't use cron since on the implementation I know the smallest unit is one minute. You can use sleep but then your process will always be running (with cron it will started every time).

To use sleep just

```
while true ; do
  if ! pgrep -f '91\.34\.124\.35' > /dev/null ; then
    sh /home/asfd.sh
  fi
  sleep 30
done
```

If your `pgrep` has the option `-q` to suppress output (as on BSD) you can also use `pgrep -q` without redirecting the output to `/dev/null`

Comment: +1; I think you have the logic backward, though - prefix the `if` conditional with `!`. Also, by using `pgrep` - which always excludes itself - instead of `ps` + `grep`, the `if` statement can be simplified to: `if ! pgrep -f '91\.34\.124\.35' > /dev/null; then`

Comment: @mklement0 Yep I didn't notice the negation in question. I corrected my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but `pgrep -q` doesn't work on Linux, unfortunately; hence my `> /dev/null` redirection; also, (a) you need `-f` in order to match against the entire _command line_, not just the process name, and (b) you don't need the `[9]` trick when you use `pgrep` (`pgrep` doesn't match itself by default); if you update again, please also reflect the changes in the bullet points below the code.

Comment: Added -f and commented about GNU/BSD versions

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should be able to reduce your script to simply

```
if ! pgrep "91\.34\.124\.35" > /dev/null; then ./your_script.sh; fi
```

To run this every 30 seconds via cron (because cron only runs every minute) you need 2 entries - one to run the command, another to delay for 30 seconds before running the same command again. For example:

```
* * * * * root if ! pgrep "91\.34\.124\.35" > /dev/null; then ./your_script.sh; fi
* * * * * root sleep 30; if ! pgrep "91\.34\.124\.35" > /dev/null; then ./your_script.sh; fi
```

To make this cleaner, you might be able to first store the command in a variable and use it for both entries. (I haven't tested this).

```
CHECK_COMMAND="if ! pgrep '91\.34\.124\.35' > /dev/null; then ./your_script.sh; fi"

* * * * * root eval "$CHECK_COMMAND"
* * * * * root sleep 30; eval "$CHECK_COMMAND"
```

---

*p.s.* The above assumes you're adding that to `/etc/crontab`. To use it in a user's crontab (`crontab -e`) simply leave out the username (`root`) before the command.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `watch`:

```
watch -n 30 launch_my_script_if_process_is_dead.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine, you can save it in a .sh file and add it to the crontab to run every 30 seconds. Let me know if you want to know how to use crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ps -ef | grep "91\.34\.124\.35" | grep -v grep > /dev/null
then
    sh home/asfd.sh
else
    echo "Process is running fine"
fi
```

No need to use `test`. `if` itself will examine the exit code.

Comment: a bit simpler: `if ps -ef | grep -q "[9]1\.34\.124\.35"; then ...`. The square brackets help filter out the grep process from the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your script in file name, myscript.sh

then you can run your script through cron,

```
 */30 * * * * /full/path/for/myscript.sh
```

or you can use while

```
 # cat script1.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 while true; do /bin/sh /full/path/for/myscript.sh ; sleep 30; done &

 # ./script1.sh
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found deamonizing critical scripts very effective.

```
http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `monit` for this task. [See docu](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html). It is available on most linux distributions and has a straightforward config. Find some [examples in this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-monit)

For your app it will look something like

```
check process myprocessname
    matching "91\.34\.124\.35"
    start program = "/home/asfd.sh"
    stop program = "/home/dfsa.sh"
```

If [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) is not available on your platform you can use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

I also found this question very similar [Repeat command automatically in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593771). It suggests to use `watch`.

Answer (score -1):

Use cron for the "loop every 30 seconds" part.

Comment: I thought minutes were the smallest granularity for cron.

Comment: You're right. http://www.linux-archive.org/centos/229078-cron-daemon-better-precision.html +1 for bringing that to attention :D